# How to get values from search suggestions after keying in text using python selenium?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

When you enter something for example apple into the search bar at https://finance.yahoo.com/ there is a search suggestions menu that appears.

[image]

I am trying to get it to return a list, dictionary or dataframe of the values in that drop down box.

For example

```
{'AAPL':['Apple Inc.','Equity - NMS','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch'],
 'AAPL.BA':['Apple Inc.','Equity - BUE','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL.BA?p=AAPL.BA&.tsrc=fin-srch'],
  .....}
```

or

```
['AAPL','Apple Inc.','Equity - NMS','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch']
['APPL.BA','Apple Inc.','Equity - BUE','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL.BA?p=AAPL.BA&.tsrc=fin-srch']
```

The last value is the hyperlink from clicking the link.

Here is my code so far,

```
options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe',options=options)

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yfin-usr-qry"]')
inputElement.send_keys('apple')
time.sleep(2)

web_elem_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='M(0)']/li/div/div")
suggests = [web_elem.text for web_elem in web_elem_list]

print(suggests)

driver.close()
```

But the output keeps coming up empty, I cant seem to locate the elements in the suggestion box.

I also tried using `web_elem_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='f470fc71']/li/div/div")`

But it doesnt have any values.

How do I,

1. Find the xpath of the suggestion box?
2. Create a dataframe, dictionary or list of all the results (including the hyperlink).

UPDATE:

I have figured out the first part of the question, the xpath had one too many /div. I updated my question and the part of the code works now.

But I still haven't figured out the second part of the question, I still cant get the "Equity - NMS" part and hyperlinks.

Comment: The elements you are searching for are in an iframe.

Comment: the searchbox isnt in an iframe but the results are in an iframe? i can see selenium keying in the values into the searchbox

Comment: i cant see an iframe at the top of the tree, could you show me?

Comment: *"But the output keeps coming up empty"* - Not quite sure if there is some other issue at your end, but I was able to run your code and get the list of matching rows. The only thing I noticed is you have `web_elem_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='M(0)']/li/div/div/div").` when the correct one is web_elem_list = driver.find_element**S**_by_xpath (which I guess is just a typo in the question?).

Comment: okay, i meant to say elements, it was a typo, ive updated my question. it still doesntwork, i get an empty list

Comment: I have figured out the first part of the question, the xpath had one too many /div. But I still haven't figured out the second part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made some changes to your script around waiting and xpaths. The result will be the suggested data in a pandas dataframe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pandas as pd

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/"
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yfin-usr-qry"]'))).send_keys('apple')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div//*[contains(text(),'Symbols')]")))
web_elem_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@data-test='search-assist-input-sugglst']/div/ul[1]/li/div")
results = pd.DataFrame()

for web_elem in web_elem_list:
    suggests=[]

    code=web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div").text
    suggests.append(code)

    name=web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div/following-sibling::div").text
    suggests.append(name)

    equity=web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/following-sibling::div").text
    suggests.append(equity)

    hyperlink=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{code}?p={code}&.tsrc=fin-srch'
    suggests.append(hyperlink)

    results=results.append(pd.Series(suggests), ignore_index=True)

print(results)

driver.close()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: hey it doesnt work, firstly, the class M(0) doesnt exist on the page anymore, i use f470fc71 instead, and secondly it says no such element: unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./div"},

Comment: also, is the thing with the hyperlink possible?

Comment: Updated the `web_elem_list` xpath so you don't rely on class in it changes. Also (re)added ChromeOptions to start the browser maximized.

Comment: hey, so i tried it, for some reason it just comes up blank again, i think it's got something to do with the ./div when you try to search again

Comment: Have you added this part to your script? `options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')`

Comment: I am at a loss here if you say you run my script as-is. I see you added the hyperlink request to the queation and can have a look at it tomorrow. That still wouldn't answer why no data at your end...

Comment: ill try to troubleshoot thanks for your hard work, oh yeah i did, sorry about that

Comment: Hyperlink added. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213412/discussion-between-0buz-and-anarchy).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul[class=f470fc71] li[role=link][data-type=quotes]")
suggestions = [web_elem.get_attribute("title") for web_elem in web_elem_list]
```

output:

```
['Apple Inc.', 'Apple Hospitality REIT, Inc.', 'Apple Inc.', 'Apple Rush Company, Inc.', 'Apple Inc.', 'ApplePie Capital']
```

Comment: yeah it works, but I only get the titles, what about the other values?