# How to save values from search suggestions using selenium?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I posted this question earlier, sorry for a repost but I can't figure out why the code works for the person who answered and not for me.

[How to get values from search suggestions after keying in text using python selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662076/how-to-get-values-from-search-suggestions-after-keying-in-text-using-python-sele)

I'll retype the question and update it with the code he posted.

When you enter something for example apple into the search bar at https://finance.yahoo.com/ there is a search suggestions menu that appears.

[image]

I am trying to get it to return a list, dictionary or dataframe of the values in that drop down box.

For example

```
{'AAPL':['Apple Inc.','Equity - NMS','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch'],
 'AAPL.BA':['Apple Inc.','Equity - BUE','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL.BA?p=AAPL.BA&.tsrc=fin-srch'],
  .....}
```

or

```
['AAPL','Apple Inc.','Equity - NMS','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch']
['APPL.BA','Apple Inc.','Equity - BUE','https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL.BA?p=AAPL.BA&.tsrc=fin-srch']
```

The last value is the hyperlink from clicking the link.

Someone posted this code below earlier,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pandas as pd

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/"
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yfin-usr-qry"]'))).send_keys('apple')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div//*[contains(text(),'Symbols')]")))
web_elem_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@data-test='search-assist-input-sugglst']/div/ul[1]/li/div")
results = pd.DataFrame()
for web_elem in web_elem_list:
    suggests=[]
    suggests.append(web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div").text)
    suggests.append(web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div/following-sibling::div").text)
    suggests.append(web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/following-sibling::div").text)
    results=results.append(pd.Series(suggests),ignore_index=True)

print(results)

driver.close()
```

But keep getting blank values in the list. I don't understand why, the person who posted says the code works for him, but I tried everything I could think of to troubleshoot. I think the xpath of the elements might not be right.

Does any one have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to use a Firefox driver?

Comment: i specifically said that question didnt answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i checked the div shows as:

```
<div class="some random code" data-id="search-assist-input-sugglst">
```

try:

```
.//div[@data-id='search-assist-input-sugglst']/ul[1]/li
```

i tried inspecting it its data-id not data-test, and and extra div before ul.

[image]

Comment: I get this error InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ./.div/div because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

Comment: edited the answer. there is an extra div on the end. sorry

Comment: ok now the first ./div part works! the next part gives an error, NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./following-sibling::div"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

Comment: are you still using
suggests.append(web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div").text)
    suggests.append(web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div/following-sibling::div").text)
    suggests.append(web_elem.find_element_by_xpath("./div/following-sibling::div").text)

i tested them and they should work with .//div[@data-id='search-assist-input-sugglst']/ul[1]/li

Comment: I tried both ways, it finally works now, I had to add some sleep timers

Comment: it may be different in your browser, to make it easier for you to test, open finance.yahoo.com in google chrome, inspect element, ctrl+f, input the xpath  ".//div[@data-id='search-assist-input-sugglst']/ul[1]/li", then just try adding "/div/div" on the end, if it works, try the next one "/div/div/following-sibling::div", and the next. if it cant find it then try editing it till it finds it in the browser.